# Fragment with Recycleview shows blank sometimes

Tags: android-fragments, android-recyclerview, fragmentmanager

I have one fragment(A) with two links, clicking each one will jump to a new fragment (B or C), the code (in onCreateView or onResume method) for jumping to the fragment B or C is as below.

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, FragmentB)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
```

Then click back button to go back to the fragmentA (same code as above), the page will be blank(white) screen **sometimes** (Not every time). After that, when I open any other pages(fragment), they will be blank. I have to restart the emulator or reinstall the app to make other pages display normally.

**Any idea about this issue? What are the possible root causes?**

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you see anything on the logcat when the screen is blank?

Comment: @ReazMurshed I don't see any errors in logcat. The AdapterA.getItemCount() returns 4, which is correct. I also have Adaptera.notifyDataSetChanged().  The layout_height of RecyclerView is match_parent.

Comment: I add the below code to to back press (getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();). Now , the behavior is click a linear layout on FragmentA, then jump to FragmentB, click back button to come back to FragmentA, click the linear layout again, the FragmentB is blank page, then click back or any other pages via the bottom navigator, all of them are blank page.